# Get wallPaper Programmatically in ios

Tags: iphone

Hello I am new bee to the iphone apps development

is there a way to get the user selected wallpapers from settings programmatically?.
i wanna create a call in progress screen so i want to set the user selected wallpaper as the background image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iOS SDK doesn't provide any way to get the user's current wallpaper.

Comment: Is it possible to get any information of current wallpaper, for example, image resolution, aggregate rgb values?